# Am I thinking of a ProgressBar or something else? Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-progressbar

I am new to Android/Java/Programming...

I am not sure if I am researching the correct term, but I am looking to have a horizontal bar on my application with no animation. The bar will show a static number from x to y based on a selected button from the user.

Can a ProgressBar be used as a standalone graphic like a bar graph? What is the correct term for me to research?

<sub>*Edited to add…*</sub>

Can I remove the user functionality from being able to adjust the seekbar?

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar is used to show progress of some operation and it used the concept of threading.
In your case I think you are talking about seekbar ,.. the value of seekbar can be changed in the application through appropriate controls..e.g onbuttonpress or editing value in textbox

Answer (score 0):

hi what you are looking for is actually a seek bar... 
[Go through this for a sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/SeekBar1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **SeekBar**.

A SeekBar is an extension of ProgressBar that adds a draggable thumb. The user can touch the thumb and drag left or right to set the current progress level or use the arrow keys.

For more details go through these links: [link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) & [link2](http://www.anddev.org/seekbar_progressbar_customizing-t6083.html)

Hope this will solve your issue.